# How can you identify an Airbus and or Boeing from the inside based on features of the interior?

Tags: boeing, airbus, aircraft-identification

I already asked a very similar question, but the answer wasn't was I was expecting. Hence this time I am more specific.

How can you recognize a plane from the inside, when you are already sitting as passenger?

In particular, is there a way to understand if you are inside a Boeing or an Airbus based on interior features of the aircraft?

The question is specifically related to the differences in interior features between aircraft built by the two companies. I am not looking for answers such as "check on your ticket", "ask the flight attendant" or "read the evacuation pamphlet".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you identify an Airbus or Boeing from the inside?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31846/how-can-you-identify-an-airbus-or-boeing-from-the-inside)

Comment: Please clarify your original question instead of asking the exact same one again. Also, what is the meaning of the word "Vel"? Google tells me it's the [spear of a Hindu war god](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vel), but I don't think that's the meaning you're after here.

Comment: @Freeman He tried  to clarify his original question, but that was rolled back. See the [associated Meta discussion](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3103/is-it-appropriate-for-an-op-to-substantially-change-a-question).

Comment: @DeltaLima, your point is very valid. However, your edit to this question seems like it would fit perfectly well on the original question, as well. My opinion has been expressed, as has yours and others. I'll not argue any further, it's not that big a deal.

Comment: This question is a little bit broad, you might consider asking how to tell the difference between particular planes that would be hard to differentiate by obvious means.  For example, maybe asking how to tell the difference between a 737 and an A320 simply by the interior?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, unfortunately, airlines (of same type) choose different seat manufacturers, etc.

It's like asking how to identify a building's architecture from one room.

We can discuss wing shapes, or a tail camera's feed on the IFE **if** there's one, but what if you're stuck on the middle seat of the middle column on a wide-body without a tail camera and no wing view?

Comment: Well, an aircraft rolls out of the factory more or less like this if you would not have an interior installed:
https://i.redditmedia.com/ylsQn1tM2TX84OOE5KhGHKaDqyLWXEmbo7aK6UpuaJc.jpg?w=1024&s=cb9c056311e5ffe4b14e4154ed31347d

Answer (score 1):

Well, the overhead bins and ceiling are quite aircraft specific, but then you need to be quite an expert to be successful in identifying an aircraft that way.

Then there is the shape of the fuselage, an A380 for example has a large radius fuselage so if you're on the lower deck the curvature of the fuselage is very low and almost straight.

A Dreamliner has very distinct windows.

An airbus has a different lightning array in the roof compared to a Boeing.

As you can see this list can go on and on depending on how skilled you are in spotting the differences between interior layouts. If you count the seats abreast you can already skip a lot of planes since they typically have 6 seats abreast or between 10 and 12 etc. Some aircraft have a widebody etc.

As a passenger the easiest way is to look at the evacuation map or look at the moving map in the IFE system.

Comment: Not sure if the info is available, but if indeed there is a consistent difference between airbus and boeing overhead bins and lighting, you may be able to answer this question definitively by showing some reference pictures.

Comment: Did you mean "lighting array" or perhaps even ["lightening array"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightening_holes) rather than lightning?